# Bootstrap Popover not moving on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code for a simple text input and I want to have a popover to give some additional information, however when I resize the page, the popover is static. 
The HTML:

```
<form action = "" id = "userInput" onsubmit = "return validateInput(this);" method = "GET">
    <div class="form-group" id = "input1">
        <label for="textInput">Input area</label>
        <input type="text" name = "userInput" class="mainInput" id="textInput" autofocus required autocomplete = "off">
    </div>
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mainInput').popover({'trigger': 'focus', 'placement': 'right', 
     'container': 'body', 'html': true, 'content': 'a simple popover'});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9517
You'll want to [use the `container` Popover option](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage) and set it to something more local to the target than `body`:

> #### `container`
>
> Appends the popover to a specific element. Example: `container: 'body'`. **This option is particularly useful in that it allows you to position the popover in the flow of the document near the triggering element - which will prevent the popover from floating away from the triggering element during a window resize.**

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9517#issuecomment-22820201):

> there's two ways to address this – either you can listen to resize and call .popover('show') on active popovers (which will resize the popover)  – or the better way is to use the container option so that the popover is positioned in the flow of the document with the triggering element

A simple example:

```
<p id="paragraph">Paragraph</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Show popover on page load
    $('#paragraph').popover({'content': 'test'}).popover('show');

    // Bind resize event
    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
        $('#paragraph').popover('show');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if visible then hide and later show

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
            if($('#div').data('bs.popover').tip().hasClass('in') == true) {
                $("#div").popover('hide');
                $("#div").popover('show');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
popover_position();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
popover_position();
});
function popover_position(){
    var get_left = ($('.mainInput').offset().left) + (($('.mainInput').width() + (padding left + paddeing right) ) /2)-($('.popover').width() / 2);        
    $('.popover').css({'left': parseInt(get_left)+'px' , 'right':'auto'});
    $('.arrow').css('left','50%');                              
 }
*(padding left + paddeing right) replace with padding left and padding right given if given for example :- ($('.mainInput').width() + 49) / 2) , here 49 is total padding(left + right)
```

Answer (score -3):

try changing 'placement' to 'auto'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mainInput').popover({'trigger': 'focus', 'placement': 'auto', 
     'container': 'body', 'html': true, 'content': 'a simple popover'});
});
```

Comment: placement is for the place, where the popover is being showed relatively from the button..